# PHP - md5 and unique $_file name

Tags: php

I have  a PHP function for uploding a image to the server,

But I am confused, I want to give a unique md5 name to currently uploaded file. Here is my code:

```
if ((getimagesize($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name']) >0) && $_FILES['user_image']['size'] > 0 && ($_FILES['user_image']['size'] < 1048576)){

        $uploaddir  = DIR.'/images/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

        // check if user have already uploaded an image, then delete 
        //it before uploading new one

        $old_file = db_user_image($user, 'image');
        if (strlen($old_file)){ 
            $delete = $uploaddir.$old_file;
            if (file_exists($delete))  
                unlink ($delete); 
        }

        db_save_user_image($user, 'image', $_FILES['user_image']['name']) ;

}
```

Please tell me how do I give unique md5 name to this files.

Comment: ... and? What are you confused about? Where are you stuck?

Comment: how to give unique md5 name to this file ?

Comment: This makes no sense for me. The md5 sum isn't more unique than the original file name or in other words two files with the same name would lead to the same md5 hash.

Comment: Why MD5 in the first place? SHA2 is a better hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `$uploadfile` declaration as follows:

```
$ext = pathinfo( $_FILES['user_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . md5(basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']) ).$ext;
```

Comment: Hi. Amal. Won't that md5/uniqid break away the extension ?

Comment: Cool there goes ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is give md5 names to the files, you need to change line

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']);
```

to

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . md5(basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']));
```

And

```
db_save_user_image($user, 'image', $_FILES['user_image']['name']) ;
```

to

```
db_save_user_image($user, 'image', md5(basename($_FILES['user_image']['name'])));
```

Comment: and unique name ? so that it wont overwrite any file

Comment: md5 is quite unique, you have to generate many md5 hashes to get a name collision.

Comment: in this answer `md5` is used two times, will the both name will be same ?

Comment: Yes, both names will be the same. But if you want to have it `md5` the name just once, you can keep it like `$md5name = md5( .. );`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `basename` on `md5`.

`basename` returns trailing name component of path

Answer (score 0):

I have added timestamp and encrypted it using `md5()`. it should generate a unique name for file.

```
   $targetFile = md5(time()).$_FILES['user_image']['name'];
```

and used `$targetFile` in place of `$_FILES['user_image']['name']` in script.

```
//Code
if ((getimagesize($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name']) >0) && $_FILES['user_image']['size'] > 0 && ($_FILES['user_image']['size'] < 1048576)){

    $uploaddir  = DIR.'/images/';
    $targetFile = md5(time()).$_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$targetFile;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

    // check if user have already uploaded an image, then delete 
    //it before uploading new one

    $old_file = db_user_image($user, 'image');
    if (strlen($old_file)){ 
        $delete = $uploaddir.$old_file;
        if (file_exists($delete))  
            unlink ($delete); 
    }

    db_save_user_image($user, 'image', $targetFile) ;
```

}

Comment: md5 is a hashing function, you don't "encrypt" anything with it.